# Window behind Desktop Panel

Tags: window, panel, gnu

I've encountered a simple problem - some windows appear behind the panel. I did my little Research and still ain't able to have an solution.

GNU Image Manipulation window behind panel:

[image: GNU Image Manipulation Window behind Panel]

Can anyone relate, get me out of this anger? It interrupted my workflow for like 20 minutes.

Comment: Please remove the solution from the question, and post it separately in the *Answers* below. It's completely fine (and often encouraged) to answer your own question.

Comment: I'd like to see a picture of the problem if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>, click on one such window, and drag it down.

Comment: I had to use also F7 along. Thanks for the Answer.

Comment: @Yikeu As per the [screenshot you added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtiDb.png), alt+mouse-drag should also work ("<Alt>Button1" is activated, first option).

Answer (score 0):

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> after clicking the window seems to be a possible the solution.

And since a picture is worth more then 1000 words:

[image]

Credits: [yikeu](https://askubuntu.com/users/780626/yikeu), i.e. the last line (= "*edit ...*") in the question, which should actually have been posted as an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to auto hide on the panels.  It may be that if you turn that feature on then off, the windows go under. Just keep autohide panels on, and hid them when you need access.